# cannot bind ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to bind ORDER BY's value to have options to sort by score or date of addition, however when I try to bind the order by value it returns to the standard order by id and doesn't listen to my command

below is my code, I've replaced the score part from the query with ? and gave it a value, but it didn't work.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
  exit();
}
session_start();
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
$search = "%{$_SESSION['search']}%";
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
if(isset($_SESSION['type'])){
  $typesql = $_SESSION['type'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['type2'])){
  $typesql2 = $_SESSION['type2'];
}
if(empty($_SESSION['type']) && empty($_SESSION['type2'])){
  $typesql = 'photographer';
  $typesql2 = 'makeup artist';
}
if($city=='Alexandria' || $city=='Cairo'){
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, location, score, img, id, type FROM artists WHERE CONCAT(name, location) LIKE ? AND visible='yes' AND type IN(?, ?) AND location IN(?) ORDER BY score  DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$results->bind_param("ssssii", $search, $typesql, $typesql2, $city, $position, $item_per_page);
}else{
  $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, location, score, img, id, type FROM artists WHERE CONCAT(name, location) LIKE ? AND visible='yes' AND type IN(?, ?) ORDER BY score  DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
  $results->bind_param("sssii", $search, $typesql, $typesql2, $position, $item_per_page);
}



$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($name, $location, $score, $img, $id, $type);

// Le fetch
  while($results->fetch()){
    echo  "<div class=\"card feed_item\" style=\"width: 20rem;\"><a id=\"wraplink\" href=\"profile.php?id=". $id."\">";
    echo  "<div class=\"imgcont\"><img class=\"card-img-top feed_img\" src=\"img/" . $img . ".jpg\"></div>";
    echo  "<div class=\"card-block\">";
    echo  "<h4 class=\"card-title\">" . $name . "</h4>";;
    echo  "</div><div class=\"card-footer ";
    if($type=="Photographer"){
      echo "footerph";
    }else{
      echo "footermk";
    }
    echo  "\"><small class=\"text-muted\"><b>". $type;
    if($city=="Egypt"){
      echo " from ". $location;
    }
    echo  "</b></small><span class=\"fb-comments-count\" data-href=\"http://setch.me/profile.php?id=".$id."\"></span></div></a></div>";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "to bind ORDER BY's value"?

Comment: You cannot use `bind_param()` to bind column names.

Comment: You should be doing this with PDO, not mysqli. But also, you're attempting to bind 6 parameters to 4 placeholders.
}else{
  $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, location, score, img, id, type FROM artists WHERE CONCAT(name, location) LIKE ? AND visible='yes' AND type IN(?, ?) ORDER BY score  DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
  $results->bind_param("sssii", $search, $typesql, $typesql2, $position, $item_per_page);
}

Comment: Nice to see that php code is still looks much as it did 15 years ago.